# Validation error reset my values why

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have a modal "A" and it has a line_item model "B" with has_many association. That means B is associated with A. I have validation for B in A's model that

```
validates_presence_f :B
 validates_associated :B
```

now in my form i have used "fields_for" to save values of B, if i submit a blank form than
validation fails and displays an error message for presence of line item B, but the fields of B's disabled, i have to reshow their fields. Can any one predict why this is happening.

here is my model :
Model A:

```
 class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :purchase_line_items
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :purchase_line_items, :reject_if => lambda {|a| a[:account_id].blank? }, :allow_destroy =>true
    validates_presence_of :purchase_line_items
        validates_associated :purchase_line_items
end
```

and Model B:

```
class PurchaseLineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :purchase
end
```

in my controller:

```
class PurchasesController < ApplicationController
def new
    @purchase = Purchase.new
    @purchase.purchase_line_items.build
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @purchase }
    end
  end
end
```

and in last my views :

```
<%= form_for @purchase, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
        <%= render 'shared/form_error', :object => @purchase %>
 <% @purchase.purchase_line_items.each_with_index do |purchase_line_item, index| %>
                           <%= render "purchase_line_items", :purchase_line_item => purchase_line_item, :index => index %>
                         <% end %>

<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

And in line item partial i have:

```
<tr id="row<%= index %>" valign="top" >
            <%= hidden_field_tag "purchase[purchase_line_items_attributes][#{index}][id]",purchase_line_item.id%>
            <td valign="top">
                <%= select_tag "purchase[purchase_line_items_attributes][#{index}][account_id]", options_from_collection_for_select(@to_accounts, :id, :name,:selected => purchase_line_item.account_id ), :include_blank => true, :class=>"full"  %>


            </td>



      <td><%= text_field_tag "purchase[purchase_line_items_attributes][#{index}][amount]", purchase_line_item.amount, :class => 'full', :id => 'total', :readonly => 'readonly',  :size => 5%></td>
            <td><%= link_to image_tag("/images/black_icon/ic_cancel.png"),{:action => :remove_line_item, :index => index}, :remote => true unless index == 0 %></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Did you copy `validates_presence_f` incorrectly?

Also, what are your controller actions, how are you re-rendering the form view after validation fails? More information is needed to debug this.

Comment: Yes it is incorrectly copied and i did not understand about re-rendering form view after validation fails, can you please explain it.

Comment: We can debug it, if you will provide your view code (where form logic is situated) and models code.

Comment: Hi @thesis i have edited my question and paste my code , hope this will help us to find some result

Comment: Thank you for update! Please also add create method from your PurchasesController. Do you have it?

Comment: i have nothing to show in create method as i did not add  nay thing in create method

Answer (score 0):

If I have correctly understood you, you have problems with nested form.

For what reason do you have `readonly` property for `:amount` field?

I do not know, why have you used approach without `fields_for`, but In this case you can not validate nested fields without it. So your code has to be something like this:

```
<%= form_for @purchase, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/form_error', :object => @purchase %>

    <%= f.fields_for :purchase_line_items do |pl| %>
        <tr id="row<%= pl.object.id %>" valign="top" >
            <%= pl.hidden_field :id %>
            <td valign="top">
                <%= pl.select :account_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@to_accounts, :id, :name, :selected => pl.object.account_id), :include_blank => true, :class=>"full" %>
            </td>

           <td><%= pl.text_field :amount, :class => 'full', :id => 'total', :readonly => 'readonly',  :size => 5 %></td>
           <td><%= link_to image_tag("/images/black_icon/ic_cancel.png"), {:action => :remove_line_item, :index => pl.object.id }, :remote => true unless index == 0 %></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Add validation to your PurchaseLineItem model to prevent saving record without :account_id.

```
class PurchaseLineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :purchase
    validates_presence_of :account_id
end
```

Actually if you will validate :account_id you do not have to use :reject_if.

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :purchase_line_items
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :purchase_line_items, :allow_destroy =>true

    validates_presence_of :purchase_line_items
    validates_associated :purchase_line_items
end
```

To be more clear, please, edit your question and add code of `create`action.